# How to measure percentage of time CloudRun Service is available (using metrics)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-monitoring

How can I measure percentage of time CloudRun Service is available using GCP metrics? I would like to measure percentage of time API is available as well as percentage of time containers are available for cloud run service. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs for Cloud Run monitoring? Don't forget that Cloud Run runs on demand. A health check will then start an instance, which will potentially raise your bill.

Comment: What do you want to log as metrics? Cloud Run can scale to 0 (default behavior). Does that mean the service is down? Hmmmm, not sure. If a request comes in, a new instance is created and served, even after hours of "unavailability". So, what's the impact on your service? The request is served, the consumer happy, so why that monitoring?

Comment: Also, you can use in the monitoring section from your Google console the option of metrics [explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer#find-me) where you can select a metric for your cloud run revision.